# c4droid error create socket

Tags: android, c, sockets

I wrote a simple networking program in C language, i tested it on my PC and everything is ok but when i try to execute this program on my smartphone android (i used c4droid to compile and execute c program on my smartphone) the terminal gives me this error: "error creating socket: Operation not permitted".

this is the code of socket

```
int sock;
sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
if (sock < 0) {
    printf("error creating socket\n");
}
```

what is problem? Is there somebody using c4droid to develop networking program in c language?

Comment: On android the application needs to have network access permission, how are you installing it? It has to be present in the manifest file.

Comment: + network io should not be done on main thread ...

Comment: i didn't write an Android app, it's just a .c file

Comment: The process must run as `root`, only root is allowed to open a raw socket. @iharob This applies only to android apps (java)

Comment: in c4droid there is the option "Run program as a root". this option in checked, so i don't know why c4droid don't execute the program

Comment: @EmanueleRiso You might want to double-check if the process really runs as root by outputting the effective uid in your error message (`geteuid()`).

Comment: it gives me number 10133, i suppose that is not in root mode

Comment: @EmanueleRiso correctamundo ;) maybe you can get a root shell via `adb` and execute it manually?